# Create a function that takes a word and returns true if the word has two consecutive identical letters

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, duplicates, boolean

// Create a function that takes a word and returns true if the word has two consecutive identical letters.

What am I doing wrong?

```
module.exports = (word) => {
    for (let i = 0; i <= word.length; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j <= word.length; j++) {
            if (word[j] == word[i]) {
                return true;
            }
        } return false;
        
    } 

};
```

Comment: Move `return false` after the next closing curly bracket. You currently have a `return` after the first outer iteration finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with only 1 loop.

```
function hasConsecutiveIdenticalLetters(word){
    for (let i = 1; i < word.length; i++) {
        if (word[i-1] === word[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I'm new to this. Appreciate the help!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: Should be `i < word.length`, otherwise you'll index out of bounds

Comment: You're right thanks, fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this like below using [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
const hasConsecutiveIdenticalLetters = (word: string) => (word).split('').some((letter, index) => letter === word[index + 1]);
```